# r.mfilter produces empty result

Tags: grass-gis, filter, grass-7.2

I am trying to apply a high pass filter to a raster that is portrayed like this in the Map Display:

[image]

For starters I double check the region:

```
> g.region raster=blenddem
> g.region -p
projection: 99 (CH1903+ / LV95)
zone:       0
datum:      ch1903
ellipsoid:  bessel
north:      210553.5
south:      208869
west:       666647
east:       668202
nsres:      0.5
ewres:      0.5
rows:       3369
cols:       3110
cells:      10477590
```

Another check with the statistics; apparently, a pretty normal raster.

```
> r.univar blenddem
 100%
total null and non-null cells: 10477590
total null cells: 4149366

Of the non-null cells:
----------------------
n: 6328224
minimum: 430.691
maximum: 600.981
range: 170.29
mean: 484.481
mean of absolute values: 484.481
standard deviation: 46.6634
variance: 2177.48
variation coefficient: 9.63164 %
sum: 3065902700.63737
```

Following [Markus Neteler's book](https://books.google.ch/books?id=G20ECAAAQBAJ&pg=PA245&lpg=PA245&dq=grass+image+processing+high+pass+filter&source=bl&ots=2vRjTedatC&sig=d9v0nBMNVeysasmNs5YeZxn9D8Y&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=grass%20image%20processing%20high%20pass%20filter&f=false) I created a simple high-pass filter:

```
> cat highpass9.txt
TITLE 3x3 High Pass
MATRIX 3
-1 -1 -1
-1  8 -1
-1 -1 -1
DIVISOR 9
TYPE S
```

I then apply the filter:

```
> r.mfilter input=blenddem output=blenddem.highpass filter=highpass9.txt
 100%
Writing raster map <blenddem.highpass>
```

Apparently everything went fine, but in the Map Display the resulting raster is entirely blank.

A quick check with the statistics shows that indeed the result is empty:

```
> r.univar blenddem.highpass
 100%
```

What is going on here? I also tried the same filter in Markus' book and result is the again a blank raster. Is there some operation missing?

**Update**: This is the result of `r.info` for the rasters in question.

```
> r.info blenddem
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Map:      blenddem                       Date: Fri May  5 11:35:05 2017    |
 | Mapset:   DEMs                           Login of Creator: desouslu        |
 | Location: Luzern                                                           |
 | DataBase: /home/desouslu/EAWAG/Projects/RasterStitching/grass              |
 | Title:                                                                     |
 | Timestamp: none                                                            |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                                            |
 |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
 |   Data Type:    DCELL                                                      |
 |   Rows:         3369                                                       |
 |   Columns:      3110                                                       |
 |   Total Cells:  10477590                                                   |
 |        Projection: CH1903+ / LV95                                          |
 |            N:   210553.5    S:     208869   Res:   0.5                     |
 |            E:     668202    W:     666647   Res:   0.5                     |
 |   Range of data:    min = 430.691497802734  max = 600.981266929298         |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Data Description:                                                        |
 |    generated by r.patch                                                    |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Comments:                                                                |
 |    r.patch input="tmp_3151920,uavdem" output="blenddem"                    |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

> r.info blenddem.highpass
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Map:      blenddem.highpass              Date: Mon May  8 11:57:13 2017    |
 | Mapset:   DEMs                           Login of Creator: desouslu        |
 | Location: Luzern                                                           |
 | DataBase: /home/desouslu/EAWAG/Projects/RasterStitching/grass              |
 | Title:    blenddem filtered using 3x3 High Pass                            |
 | Timestamp: none                                                            |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                                            |
 |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
 |   Data Type:    FCELL                                                      |
 |   Rows:         3369                                                       |
 |   Columns:      3110                                                       |
 |   Total Cells:  10477590                                                   |
 |        Projection: CH1903+ / LV95                                          |
 |            N:   210553.5    S:     208869   Res:   0.5                     |
 |            E:     668202    W:     666647   Res:   0.5                     |
 |   Range of data:    min = -nan  max = -nan                                 |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Data Description:                                                        |
 |    generated by r.mfilter                                                  |
 |                                                                            |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: In the book (3rd edition, p 309) we wrote TYPE P  (not S)... Please use a more recent edition of the book - for example the 3rd edition (your link points to the very old 1st edition from 2002).

Comment: BTW: The erratum was noted here back then: https://grassbook.org/errata/errata-1st-edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was identified by Anna Petrášová at the [GRASS users list](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2017-May/076483.html). The flag `TYPE` in the filter is incorrect, it should `P` instead of `S`:

```
TITLE 3x3 High Pass
MATRIX 3
-1 -1 -1
-1  8 -1
-1 -1 -1
DIVISOR 9
TYPE P
```

The definition of the [S flag](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.mfilter.html) is not fully clear to me:

> TYPE
>       The filter type. S means sequential, while P mean parallel. If not specified, the default is S.
>
> Sequential filtering happens in place. As the filter is applied to the raster map layer, the category values that were changed in
>   neighboring cells affect the resulting category value of the current
>   cell being filtered.

But it is clear the `S` option does not correspond to a high-pass filter, as stated in the book. The same is true for low-pass filters, in this case the `P` option must be used too.

Comment: Please use a more recent edition of the book - for example the 3rd edition (your link points to the very old 1st edition from 2002).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Are any of the newer editions online?

Comment: Please find the references for all 3 editions published so far at https://grassbook.org/

Answer (score 1):

Using your filter in the NC demo dataset works for me:

```
>r.mfilter elevation out=elev_filtered filter=test.filter
> r.info -r elev_filtered
min=-0.2548591
max=152.8889
```

Could you test if this works for you ? And possibly provide the r.info of your input map ?

Comment: Hi there Moritz, welcome to GIS.SE. Please take the time to read the [welcoming tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). To your questions: with the Carolina dataset the filter appears to be working, since I get valid *min* and *max* values with `r.info`. I included the output for the rasters in the question above; as you can see, in this case the filter seems to be returning `nan` across the entire span of the raster.